# Can You Invest in Marijuana Companies Legally?

Tags: us-federal-government, drugs, investment, medical-marijuana

I read this article today: [Floundering Weed Stocks Test Wall Street’s Faith in 2024 Rebound](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2023-12-17/floundering-weed-stocks-test-wall-street-s-faith-in-2024-rebound?srnd=premium)

It said "stocks underlying the industry are floundering, with even the bulls growing tired of waiting. An index tracking the shares of 100 marijuana-related companies has tumbled more than 15% so far this year, after touching an all-time low in October."

Question: How can there even be marijuana stocks that are legal to invest in, isn't it still a Schedule 1 Felony federally?  Paraphrased: How can I hand money to someone who is effectively facilitating federal crimes in America?

Maybe I don't comprehend the legal landscape (why I'm asking), yet that feels like investing in the Medellín Cartel and Pablo Escobar.  "Well, somebody somewhere allows cocaine use..."